# Add my "Defines" to an enum in C

Tags: c, enums, c-preprocessor

I have a few defines in C:

```
#define My_CheckButton_1 "Check1"
#define My_CheckButton_2 "Check2"
#define My_CheckButton_3 "Check3"
```

I would like to add all the My_CheckButton_x to an enum, so I can run on all of them in a loop.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enum has integral type in C, so you will not get the string value if you move them to an enum, but an integral value. If you need the string values, you will need a function to do the enum-to-string conversion. It is not the same, but maybe using an array could be an alternative:

```
static const char *My_CheckButtons[] = {"Check1", "Check2", ... , "CheckN"};
```

Of course you would still have to remember the size of the array. You can also do a combination of both and use the enum value as index into the string-array.

Comment: That doesn't compile; you can't initialize a `char**` with a list of strings like that. You can do `static const char *My_CheckButtons[] = { ... };`, which also lets you compute the array length using `sizeof My_CheckButtons / sizeof My_CheckButtons[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
typedef enum{Check1, Check2, Check3} My_CheckButton;
```

Comment: Change ( ... ) by { ... }